# String Trim in Java

Tags: java, string

I have to trim (including whitespaces within the string) all the strings in a list. I have written a method to do this trim using regex. I am using `strArray[i] = trimString(strArray[i]);` instead of using an enhanced for loop. I assume since string is immutable this way of assigning back to the same array element is correct. Am I right?

```
public void trimStringArray(String[] strArray){
    if(strArray!= null && strArray.length > 0){
        for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
            strArray[i] = trimString(strArray[i]);
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, `&& ... > 0` can be dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's fine, and you wouldn't be able to use the enhanced for loop. However, you can simplify your code by getting rid of the `length > 0` check - there's no harm in it executing the loop 0 times... and personally I would *usually* expect the parameter to such a method to be non-null anyway, leading to code like this:

```
public void trimStringArray(String[] strArray) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(strArray);
    for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        strArray[i] = trimString(strArray[i]);
    }
}
```

([`Preconditions.checkNotNull`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull%28T%29) comes from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) in this case.)

You *could* leave it accepting `null` - but do you really have many situations where it's valid to have a null array, but you want to trim everything if it's not?

As a readability thing, I'd also encourage you to include a bit more whitespace - it's definitely a personal preference, but I know I find code with no spaces, such as this, harder to read:

```
for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
```

Comment: I don't there are many cases I would have a null array - but just added it as a safety check because it is a webservice request which I am working on. Yes , I would have to trim if it is not null. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon. Should it be for (int i=0; i<strArray.length; i++) {

Comment: @PunterVicky: I gave up doing this sort of thing "for safety" a long time ago - I generally find it's safer to make *stricter* assertions and check them early. If you end up in an unexpected situation, it's best to error out quickly rather than ending up wiping out some data etc.

Comment: @PunterVicky: Well it's up to you, but see my example in my answer the spacing I'd use.

Comment: Thanks again Jon. This is the first piece of code that gets executed prior to validation - so thought I could have this check here. This is an optional element in the schema hence have added a null check. Sorry , If I didn't understand your statement completely :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code is correct.

Note that the `strArray.length > 0` check is redundant: the loop condition will automatically take care of the case when `strArray` has zero length.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is ok to do. I would add add final in method signature. By adding final you can make sure mistakenly you are not re-assigning references (added safety).

```
public void trimStringArray(final String[] strArray){
```

Comment: would final stop another string from being added to this array?

Comment: No, it wouldn't stop manipulating (add/remove) internal content of strArray. It would be compile time error if you try to assign strArray to another object.